# How to enter a LocalDate value into BlueJ "Create Object" dialog box

Tags: java, bluej, localdate

I'm not trying to format the date in YYYY-MM-DD or dd/MM/YYYY. I'm asking about the literal format of LocalDate.

I just started learning Java and I am using this IDE called BlueJ. and I want to create a test method.

The screenshot will show what I am trying to do [image: Ignore the Error part at the bottom]

Now since from the constructor we know that it requires a int, LocalDate and a double. I've searched online and found that

> https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-working-with-localdate-localtime-localdatetime-tutorial-with-examples/
>
> java.time.LocalDate: A LocalDate instance holds a date without a time
>   zone, in ISO-86011 calendar system. LocalDate has the default format
>   ‘YYYY-MM-DD’ as in ‘2016-12-12’.

So I would put a normal number in 10001 for the testID and double would be something like 50.5
I also know that for it to register a string (if it was needed) I would need to enclose it within "string"

But I've tried all sorts of way to put in the date and I would be left with an error

2018-05-30,30-05-2018,30/05/2018 would give me

```
Error: incompatible types: Int cannot be converted to java.time.LocalDate
```

"30/05/2018" on the other hand would give me

```
Error: Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to java.time.LocalDate
```

If I try 30.05.2018 it would say

```
Error: ';' expected
```

If I try '2018-05-30' it would say

```
Error: unclosed character literal
```

I ran out of ways to try it. So if you could tell me how I should put it in there, that would be great.

I just really need to know how BlueJ wants me to input it. Cause the resources for BlueJ is so sparse online.

---

Code:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Write a description of class TestPaper here.
 * 
 * @author (your name) 
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class TestPaper
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int testID;
    private LocalDate testDate;
    private double testMarks;
    private ArrayList<MCQ> MCQDetails;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class TestPaper
     */
    public TestPaper(int testID, LocalDate testDate, double testMarks)
    {
        this.testID = testID;
        this.testDate = testDate;
        this.testMarks = testMarks;
        MCQDetails = new ArrayList<MCQ>() ; 
    }

/**
 * Accessor Method getTestID to get the testID
 *
 * @return int value of the choice ID
 */
public int getTestID(){
    return testID;
}

/**
 * Mutator Method to set the testID
 * 
 *  @param int format of the testID to set
 */
public void setTestID(int testID){
    this.testID = testID;
}

/**
 * Accessor Method getTestMarks to get the Test Marks
 *
 * @return double value of the test marks 
 */
public double getTestMarks(){
    return testMarks;
}

/**
 * Mutator Method to set the testMarks
 * 
 *  @param String format of the choice Description to be set
 */
public void setTestMarks(double testMarks){
    this.testMarks = testMarks;
}

    /**
 * Accessor Method getTestDate to get the testDate
 *
 * @return LocalDate value of the testDate
 */
public LocalDate getTestDate(){
    return testDate;
}

/**
 * Mutator Method to set the testDate
 * 
 *  @param LocalDate format of the testDate to set
 */
public void setTestDate(LocalDate testDate){
    this.testDate = testDate;
}

/**
 * Method addMCQ will allow users to add a MCQ Object to the list of MCQ
 *
 * @param addMCQ a MCQ Object
 * @return boolean will return true if it is successfully added or false if not
 */
public boolean addMCQ(MCQ MCQName)
{
    return MCQDetails.add(MCQName);
}

/**
 * Method removeMCQ to remove an MCQ object from the Arraylist
 *
 * @param MCQName A parameter of type MCQ 
 */
public void removeMCQ(MCQ MCQName)
{
    MCQDetails.remove(MCQName);
}

/**
 * Method listMCQ to return a list of MCQ arraylist
 *
 * @return The return value of MCQDetails (MCQ Arraylist)
 */
public ArrayList<MCQ> listMCQ()
{
    return MCQDetails;
}

    public MCQ findMCQ(int MCQID)
{
    for(MCQ m : MCQDetails)
    {
        if(m.getQuestionID() == MCQID)
        {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: where's the code that implements all this?

Comment: I'll add it now.It's just a simple program really.

Comment: I don't use bluej, so not sure what kind of expression it accepts. Can you put code like `LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30)`? Or a string `"2018-05-30"` (not sure if you already tried double quotes)?

Comment: I tried LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30) and I got Error: cannot find symbol - variable LocalDate

Comment: You need to import java.time.LocalDate;

Comment: I did, it's imported, just did not put it in the codes above

Comment: Is it imported in the right class?

Comment: I've edited the codes to include the part i did not copy paste just now. 
What I really need is just to figure out how BlueJ wants me to put it in

Comment: Just guessing, but what if you try `java.time.LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30)`? (if it can't find the class, maybe using the full name...)

Comment: @Hugo
OMG it worked. Apparently BlueJ has to accept it as java.time.LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30). Can you put it as an answer and I'll confirm that answer

Comment: Just another detail: a date [has no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date). Classes like `LocalDate` just **holds** values (in this case, it has year, month and day values), but a date itself has no format at all. The same date can be **represented** in many different formats: `May 30th 2018`, `2018-05-30`, `30/05/18` are different formats, but all represent the same date. A date object just holds the values, and you can choose whatever format you want to represent it.

Comment: When you **print** a `LocalDate`, it implicity calls `toString()`, which by default chooses `yyyy-MM-dd` format, which is a [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), but as I said in the previous comment, that's just one of the many possible ways to format a date (although the **value** always stays the same). Telling that *"a date has a format"* is wrong and misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Include package

As discussed in the comments, the solution is to add the code that creates the `LocaDate`, but bluej needs the fully qualified class name with the package prefix “java.time.”:

```
java.time.LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30)
```

Not sure why it doesn't work with just `LocalDate.of(...)` (even with the class correclty imported), but at least this works.

---

Just another detail: [a date has no format](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/). Classes like `LocalDate` just holds values (in this case, it has year, month and day values), but a date itself has no format at all. The same date can be represented in many different formats: `May 30th 2018`, `2018-05-30`, `30/05/18` are different formats, but all represent the same date. A date object just holds the values, and you can choose whatever format you want to represent it.

When you print a `LocalDate`, it implicity calls `toString()`, which by default chooses `yyyy-MM-dd` format, which is a [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, but as I said, that's just one of the many possible ways to format a date (although the value always stays the same). Telling that *"a date has a format"* is wrong and misleading.

Comment: Yeah I dunno why BlueJ has to take it as java.time.LocalDate.of(2018, 5, 30) but hey, I'm glad it worked. took me a few hours to figure it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the LocalDate in the call, such as:

```
TestPaper (2018-05-30, LocalDate.parse("2018/05/30"), 30/05/2018);
```

There are other static methods within LocalDate you can use. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) for more examples.

From your comment above, don't forget your import:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
```